# How to encode the query part of the NSURL

Tags: ios, encode, nsurl

(iOS 8.0+)

I want to use NSURL to pass some parameters in query part, like this:

```
NSURLComponents *components = [[NSURLComponents alloc] initWithString:@"ft://market/detail"];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username" : @"高高高", @"from" : @"中国北京"};
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString *key in parameters.allKeys) {
    [items addObject:[[NSURLQueryItem alloc] initWithName:key value:parameters[key]]];
}
components.queryItems = items;
NSURL *url = components.URL;
NSLog(@"url : %@", url);
```

However, when I receive the `URL` and parse it, I find that the Chinese characters passed in the `query` part are abnormal, and I used `NSURLComponents` to parse the URL like this:

```
NSURLComponents *anaComponents = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:url.absoluteString];
NSMutableDictionary *queryParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (NSURLQueryItem *querItem in anaComponents.queryItems) {
    [queryParams setObject:querItem.value forKey:querItem.name];
}
NSLog(@"queryParams : %@", queryParams);
```

The following is the debug log:

```
url : ft://market/detail?username=%E9%AB%98%E9%AB%98%E9%AB%98&from=%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD%E5%8C%97%E4%BA%AC
queryParams : {
    from = "\U4e2d\U56fd\U5317\U4eac";
    username = "\U9ad8\U9ad8\U9ad8";
}
```

The problem now seems to be that there is a problem with encoding and decoding of characters such as Chinese, even if `[parameters[key] stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]]` method is used to encode the query value, it is still wrong when decoding.

The query part I want to parse is like this : `@{@"username" : @"高高高", @"from" : @"中国北京"};`.

Hope for your helps here, Thanks sincerely.

Comment: From the docs: "NSURLComponents instance automatically encodes the name and value properties, you should not percent-encode these strings."

Comment: Are you encoding and decoding locally on iOS, or are you receiving the URL to decode from some other software?

Comment: "\U4e2d\U56fd\U5317\U4eac" is a debug description of unicode chars, to see real glyphs you should print it directly, for example in the loop do: `NSLog(@"%@ = %@", querItem.name, querItem.value);`

Comment: I had tried what you said, but I still cannot get the correct result, all 
of the results are like this `\U4e2d\U56fd\U5317\U4eac`  @battlmonstr

Comment: I was running the project in my iPhone, it was still show me like `\U4e2d\U56fd\U5317\U4eac`.

Comment: What happens if you do `BOOL x = [querItem.value isEqualToString:parameters[querItem.name]]; NSLog(@"x = %d", x);`

Are they equal or not?

Comment: It's really strange that they are the same, and the debug log is the correct Chinese characters what need, but when I set the results to the dictionary and set to the `UITextView`, the encoding is incorrect. @battlmonstr

Comment: Thank you for help @battlmonstr , I know what the problem is.

Comment: What was it?...

Comment: The query parameters that are parsed into the query part are correct, but the way the NSString's `stringWithFormat:` method displays is a Unicode encoded content that I think is wrong.